# glmer coefficients extraction

Tags: mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, lme4-nlme

I would need to extract some coeffients after an analysis performed with `glmer` in R. As I am not an expert I have tried to simulate data to see where I need to find those coefficients. But I am even more lost. Because the simple estimates do not fit with the values I generated. I am sure it is a miss understanding from my side, but I am stuck.

```
library(car)
library(lme4)

#Data generation: 10 random level, 1 fixed factor and 50 replicates
A <- array(0,50)
a <- array(0,10)
B <- 0
for(i in 1:10){
    for(j in 1:50){
    a[i] <- rnorm(1,0,0.8)
    A[j] <- rnorm(1,0.9,0.2)+a[i]
    B <- c(B,A[j])
    A[j] <- rnorm(1,0.2,0.2)+a[i]
    B <- c(B,A[j])}}
    B <- B[-1]

Yvar <- expit(B)
Fac <- rep(c(0,1),500)
Ran <- array(0,50)
Ran1 <- 0
for(i in 1:10){
    Ran1 <- rep(i,100) 
    Ran <- c(Ran,Ran1)}
Ran <- factor(Ran[-c(1:50)])

data <- data.frame(Yvar,Fac,Ran)

boxplot(Yvar~Ran)
boxplot(Yvar~Fac)
```

When I performe a simple glm, the estimate are close to what I generated:

```
plogis(0.7893)=~ mean(data[Fac==0]$Yvar)

mean(data$Yvar)

summary(mod <- glm(Yvar ~Fac,family="binomial"))

Call:
glm(formula = Yvar ~ Fac, family = "binomial")

Deviance Residuals: 
     Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max  
-1.15176  -0.23548   0.02702   0.26193   0.90161  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)   0.7893     0.0965   8.180 2.85e-16 ***
Fac          -0.6166     0.1318  -4.678 2.90e-06 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 143.98  on 999  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 121.80  on 998  degrees of freedom
AIC: 1149.7

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 3
```

However when I performe a glmm with glmer, I am not even close to the paramaters estimated:

```
plogis(2.0505)≠mean(data[Fac==0]$Yvar).

Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
 Family: binomial ( logit )
Formula: Yvar ~ Fac + (1 | Ran)

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
  1037.7   1052.4   -515.8   1031.7      997 

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-2.36528 -0.65581 -0.30745 -0.00159  0.72135 

Random effects:
 Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Ran    (Intercept) 0        0       
Number of obs: 1000, groups: Ran, 10

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)   2.0505     0.1407   14.57   <2e-16 ***
Fac          -1.6866     0.1675  -10.07   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
    (Intr)
Fac -0.840
```

Do you have an idea how I can extract the coefficient of the glmer?

Comment: interesting.  haven't had a chance to look at it closely, but the difference is indeed surprising.  Especially if random effects variance is estimated as zero, would expect `glm` and `glmer` parameters to be (nearly?) identical ...

Comment: the fundamental problem is that you are fitting non-integer data with a binomial GLM.  It is alarming (to me) that the results are nonsensical; for that reason I hope to enter this as an issue at https://github.com/lme4/lme4/issues , but you *did* get a warning that you didn't tell us about (`non-integer #successes in a binomial glm!`) -- right?

Comment: Indeed I did not think it was so important as it worked well with the glm. When I transformed the response variable: Response <- cbind((round(Yvar*100)),(100-(round(Yvar*100)))) The estimation is ok. Thank you for the comment!